# Dedicated Multiplayer Server Money Sharing

Tags: farming-simulator-2017

I have recently purchased a dedicated server for individuals in my community to play on in Farming Simulator 2017. I would like there to be a shared money pool (so to speak), where all players' actions would add to and remove from that overall wealth.

I essentially would like it to act as if everybody is an admin (separate accounts off and everybody admin means everybody gets to share the wealth). My question is, is there a way to achieve this without giving every person on the server the admin password? I looked up mods but came up with nothing!